# Always push to different branch on remote, without setting upstream

Tags: git

It strikes me that git can practically make coffee while playing a cello, so it must be powerful enough to do this.

I'm developing an app, with the code stored on github, and am in the process of migrating it from Heroku to OpenShift. As a result, `origin` is github and I have a branch named `migrate_to_openshift`. This branch's upstream is `origin/migrate_to_openshift`, and I don't want to change that - I want a simple `git push` to push to the same branch on github.

However, to deploy to OpenShift, I have to push to `master` on the openshift remote. At the moment, that means I need to `git push openshift migrate_to_openshift:master`, which is a bit long-winded. Can I configure git so that `git push openshift` will do that by default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the git-config documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html):

> `remote.<name>.push`
>        The default set of "refspec" for git-push(1). See git-push(1).

So, setting `remote.openshift.push` to `migrate_to_openshift:master` should do that, although it will make that happen *every* time you run `git push openshift` (with no additional arguments), regardless of which branch you're on.

(I generally find these things too overly tricky to bother with—I just make an alias for special cases, e.g., `git config alias.po "push openshift migrate_to_openshift:master"` and then `git po` to run that.  Otherwise I start relying on the magic, which I can find but never remember easily, and then I try to do something like this on a coworker's setup and it explodes messily.)

Comment: Thanks. The alias is probably the sensible way to go, as you point out.